# How can Java Applications communicate with MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab

I have some mex files that urgently need to be called via MATLAB, there is currently no way around. However, I really despise MATLAB's GUI (in)possibilities and would like to create some e.g. JavaFX Apps.

My question: how can a Java app's communicate with a **running** MATLAB instance?

I know that you can include Java objects into MATLAB, however I would prefere to have a standalone Java app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java can execute commands via command line for example:

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
 process.waitFor();
```

So it is possible to execute a MATLAB script via command line in Java.

In MATLAB it is possible to write files with any data needed. I don't remember the exact way you may do this. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html gives an example:

```
x = 0:.1:1;
A = [x; exp(x)];

fileID = fopen('exp.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%6s %12s\n','x','exp(x)');
fprintf(fileID,'%6.2f %12.8f\n',A);
fclose(fileID);
```

It is some kind of a workaround but it should work and it is not really hard to implement.

**Update**.

If Matlab is already running and you want to communicate with it in another application (Java), it may be done using a network connection through the localhost. Matlab may listen to some predefined port (for code example see http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11802-matlab-tcp-ip-code-example ) and do some action when a "start" trigger is sent via Java (or even some data along with the trigger). In Java you may use the Socket class (some code example may be found here http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/core-java-sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html ).

Also it may be done writing data into files. For example, Java adds some command to some file with predefined name (`command.txt`). Matlab scans this file in a loop and when something is found there it starts calculation (and Java application waits for results in some `results.txt` file).

Comment: Thats a nice answer thanks, however I need to mention, that my Matlab instance is already open (and needs to be already open) and I did not find any guideline how to run a script from command line in a running matlab environment :(

Comment: @RobertStettler There is a crazy variant to imitate a command. Matlab may scan some file in a loop and search for a command to start calculations there. For example "command.txt" is empty, Matlab is idle (scans an empty document and does nothing or sleeps). Than Java application writes down command "start" and Matlab starts to process data.

Comment: @RobertStettler also I'm pretty sure that Matlab is able to monitor incoming network connection ( http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11802-matlab-tcp-ip-code-example ). You may just make it listening to some port on the local host and then send a "start" trigger via Java (or even some data along with trigger).

Comment: That last comment is actually not a bad idea. Do you mind to include it in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start a server in Matlab that listens on a specific port to send/receive data to/from a Java client. By using the `eval` Matlab command you could even invoke scripts/command/etc. remotely controlled by a Java client.

You might want to have a look at [this code example](https://gist.github.com/julianthome/0731d69081cedf357a8b384c191af8ad).